# How to tactfully make food blessings in front of a gentile?

Tags: blessing, gentiles, how-to, social-convention

Say you're in a business meeting with a gentile. Food is served (kosher of course!). How can you go about reciting the before and after blessings without causing any embarrassment or awkwardness to either party?

I am looking for an answer that will provide some kiddush Hashem and minimize any possible chillul Hashem.

Comment: Many gentiles are familiar with the idea of reciting "grace" over food. It might not be that weird to ask for a moment to say grace.

Comment: @doubleaa unlike the Christian form of grace, the Jewish grace is said in Hebrew

Comment: First of all, it can be said in any language. Additionally, you'd be asking to say it to yourself quietly.

Comment: I thought about saying it in English but I only know the blessings by heart in Hebrew.

Comment: Good thing this question isn't about you but is purely theoretical. If you'd like to [edit] to change the theoretical case you can.

Comment: No need - one can always memorize or bring the proper siddur if necessary.

Answer (score 9):

If all you're having is *borei nefashot* foods, it's probably not necessary to do anything different. Say the *bracha rishonah* quietly before you take a bite, and a *borei nefashot* at the end. It's not that long.

If you have to make an *al hamichya*, i would just tell them, "i'll be with you in a second, i just have to say a short grace after eating." As Double AA mentioned in a comment, many gentiles are familiar with the concept.

And if you're having bread and need to wash and bentch, treat it as a teaching opportunity. Explain to them: "Before eating bread, Jews do a ritual handwashing and say a blessing. When we finish eating, we say grace after the meal, in Hebrew." That should alleviate any odd looks, assuming you're eating with a civilized person. They may even ask for more information, or to hear you say it out loud. :)

Basically, don't worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

make it loud and proud, most people respect faith and religion, its just the media that besmirches faith and honesty